# Estimating covariance matrix from Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Roughly speaking, the Mahalanobis distance is the distance between a multivariate Gaussian distribution (μ, Σ) and a point. If the Gaussian distribution represents a class, we can classify new points by choosing the class with the minimum distance.

I'm giving an N*D trained data as class data, and I need to calculate mu and inverse of Sigma.

```
Estimates the parameters for the mahalanobis distance for a specific class.
:param x_class: a (n x d) numpy array, containing n samples with d features coresponding to a specific class.
:return: tuple of (mu, inv_Si)
    where mu     is a (d,)   numpy array
          inv_Si is a (d, d) numpy array.
```

I'm using MLE estimator, I get a correct mean, but I don't correct inverse covariance matrix.

The train data is big 74*4 N*D features.

What are the alternative estimators that can fit the data correctly ?

I tried to use other estimators like OAS, I get incorrect mean and incorrect inverse covariance matrix.

The best estimator was EmpiricalCovariance estimator. But I get a correct mean from it, but with a inverse covariance matrix that has minus difference of 2.0 or 3.0 values against the test case.

Comment: You don't need to compute the inverse of Sigma. You need to solve linear systems

Comment: @tschm So you mean I can estimate just the mean, and what about of estimating the inverse of the covariance matrix, how would I estimate it or solve the linear systems ? Can you post an answer please with pseudo code ? or further details ?

Comment: Let's say you see Ax = b or x = inv(A)*b. That does not imply you should compute inv(A). Never do that! It means x = linsolve(A,b).

Comment: I don't see why you need inv(Sigma) here. The Mahalanobis distance is a z-Score for data (in multiple dimensions). You can estimate mu, you can estimate sigma... The M-distance for any given point x is then (x - mu)/sqrt(x'*Sigma*x)